# Unittests: Create Mock as property in the UnitTest class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

When writing Unittests, I wonder if it is best practice to create a property for the mock like in this example (I am seeing this all over the tutorials in the internet):

```
 public class CartControllerTests
  {
      private CartController controller;
      private Mock<IPaymentService> paymentServiceMock;

      [SetUp]
      public void Setup()
      {
          cartServiceMock = new Mock<ICartService>();
      }
  }
```

(Taken and adjusted from https://softchris.github.io/pages/dotnet-moq.html#full-code)

Because when I write several Unittests and Setup the mock for a specific behaviour (per test), I think it could be possible, that one setup in the first test could override the second setup in the next test.

Wouldn't it be better to create an own Mock for every Unittest, and just setup it for the specific  Test?

Comment: While a matter of opinion, if a test class will have multiple tests that require isolated behaviors, then each mock should be created individually within each test with a setup specific to the test case

Comment: Your `Setup` method will run for every unit test, so what you're doing will work the way you want it to. You'll have a new mock for every test. As @Nkosi mentioned, there are downsides - it means that tests are less self-contained. There are some trade-offs. This approach can get way out of hand when there are too many mocks. You might like the Moq.Automock nuget package.

Comment: @ScottHannen: Ah ok, thank you very much. If you post your comment as answer, i will accept it

Comment: It doesn't feel like much of an answer - it's more of an opinion.